# Parallel.ForEach with ListView

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I have the following code:

```
Parallel.ForEach(this.listView2.CheckedItems,
                    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
                    (CheckedItem) =>
                    {
                         //do something
                    });
```

and I get the following **compile** error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I searched about how to use listview with tasks but couldn't find anything.

**How can I use Parallel.ForEach with ListView?**

Comment: Right and reason for that is because the CheckedItems collection is just that, a collection and so it can't `infer` the type.  What is the underlying type of the collection?

Comment: I'm new to c# so speak english please :P

Comment: Okay, so what types of objects did you add to the Items collection of the ListView?  Strings?  Integers?  A complex type that you created?

Comment: just strings. and if you can help me please post the answer so I can accept it

Comment: Try changing your code to the following. If it works I'll post as an answer.

    Parallel.ForEach<string>(this.listView2.CheckedItems, 
        new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, 
        (CheckedItem) => 
        { 
            //do something 
        });

Comment: 2 more errors now: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ListView.CheckedListViewItemCollection' to 'System.Collections.Concurrent.OrderablePartitioner<string>' 
and

Argument 3: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Action<string,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState,long>'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ListView.CheckedItems returns a [CheckedItemsListViewCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkedlistviewitemcollection.aspx) which doesn't implement any of the generic collection types since it resides from back in the .NET 1.x area where generics were not available yet. You need to tell PLinq what type of items are residing in the collection. If you read the documentation, CheckedListViewCollection contains [ListViewItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.aspx). You can use Linq to explicitly specify the type by using the Cast extension method.

```
Parallel.ForEach(this.listView2.CheckedItems.Cast<ListViewItem>(),
                    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 },
                    (CheckedItem) =>
                    {
                         //do something
                    });
```

This whole discussion will probably become obsolete since ListViews (and hence, most other winform controls) can only be accessed from the UI thread. If you have to go parallel, you can create a copy of the data within a ListViewItem and work over that.

Comment: I would rather use `Cast` instead of `OfType`. If you use `OfType` and mistakenly specify incorrect type, it will silently return an empty collection. But `cast` would loudly fail with an exception, which is much better, because you immediately see your mistake.

Comment: @svick - Spot on, my intent was to use cast (see the description) although when typing the code example, i mistakenly used OfType. I'll change it right away

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to the following. Please note for this to work you will need to add a `using` statement for System.Linq because of the Cast extension method.

```
Parallel.ForEach<string>(this.listView2.CheckedItems.Cast<string>(), 
    new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 }, 
    (CheckedItem) => 
    { 
        //do something 
    });
```

That should compile because you're explicitly defining the type as the CLR cannot infer types from a non-generic collection.

Comment: but I couldn't use the item.subitems with this answer

Comment: The collection contains `LIstViewItem`s, not `string`s, so your code will fail at runtime with an exception.

Comment: @svick You are correct, and Polity answered it correctly. Thanks.